# Project diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I want to draw the following project diagram with [tikz](/questions/tagged/tikz).
[image]

My attempt is below:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0, 0) rectangle (1.5, 0.5) node (R1)  [midway] {ASSESS};

\draw rectangle (4.5, 0.5) node (right of = R1, R2)  [midway] {ENROLL};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the tikz `chains` and `shapes` libraries like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain,
  node distance=0mm,
  every node/.style={
    signal, 
    text=black,
    draw=white,
    minimum height=1cm,
    ultra thick, 
    signal to=east,
    signal from=west
  }
]

\node [on chain,shade,left color=blue!50,right color=cyan,signal from=none,minimum width=4cm] {ASSESS};
\node [on chain,shade,left color=yellow,right color=green] {ENROLL};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use the smartdiagram package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{sequence item border color=white}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{ASSESS,ENROLL}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks for very useful answer.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You're welcome!